# Google drive access from django-python

Tags: python, django, google-oauth

In `Django` I implemented social login using the social auth app and I followed [this link](https://hashedin.com/blog/a-guide-to-using-social-login-with-django/) to configure it.
`Goolge OAuth` is working good; `google-oauth2` access token is stored in extra data field.

Now I want to list google drive files using this access token. I tried with this.

```
def drive(request):
    user = request.user
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
    response = requests.get(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
        params={'access_token': social.extra_data['access_token']})
    print(response)
    return render(request, 'home/drive.html', {'checking':response})
```

I am getting a `200` response, but I don't know how to list files.

I'm using `django 2.0.3` and `python 3.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the settings to Re-prompt Google OAuth2 users to refresh the refresh_token by

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'access_type': 'offline'
}

and used a google-auth library to authenticate to Google APIs

```
def drive(request):
    user = request.user
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
    creds=google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(social.extra_data['access_token'])
    drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    files = drive.files().list().execute()
```

References:

1. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app
2. https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html
3. https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html

Comment: Hi, After trying this solution I got this error : HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes